# Ruby paragraph mode vs Awk and Perl

Tags: ruby, bash, perl, awk, record

Suppose you have a file with five blocks of data separated by two or more `\n` to separate the records (a common text format).

If you run [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) with `RS=""` you set awk to separate the blocks into records. You can then set `FS=\n` to separate the lines of the blocks into fields.

Example:

```
$ cat lines
f1, r1
f2, r1 then 2 \n:

f1, r2 then 3 \n:


f1,r3
f2,r3 then 4 \n:



f1, r4
f2,r4 then 6 \n: 





f1,r5
```

The [idiomatic](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Multiple-Line) way to separate the blocks into records and the lines into fields with awk is:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=""; FS="\n"; OFS="|"}
       {$1=$1; printf "NR: %d, NF: %d, record: \"%s\"\n", NR, NF, $0 }' lines
NR: 1, NF: 2, record: "f1, r1|f2, r1 then 2 \n:"
NR: 2, NF: 1, record: "f1, r2 then 3 \n:"
NR: 3, NF: 2, record: "f1,r3|f2,r3 then 4 \n:"
NR: 4, NF: 2, record: "f1, r4|f2,r4 then 6 \n: "
NR: 5, NF: 1, record: "f1,r5"
```

No matter how many `\n` separate the blocks, as long as 2 or more, it's a record.

(With [gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk) exactly the same result can be obtained by setting `RS="\n\n+"` instead of `RS=""` since gawk supports a regex to separate records. Thanks [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) for pointing out the difference between POSIX awk and gawk on that)

While [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) does not support using a regex for the input record separator, there are two methods to set an equivalent paragraph mode. You can either use the `-00` command line switch or set the input record separator, `$/`, to a null string:

```
$ perl  -00 -F"\n" -lane 'BEGIN{ $\=""; $,="|"} 
                    printf "NR: %d, NF: %d, record: \"%s\"\n", $., scalar(@F), join($,,@F)' lines
NR: 1, NF: 2, record: "f1, r1|f2, r1 then 2 \n:"
NR: 2, NF: 1, record: "f1, r2 then 3 \n:"
NR: 3, NF: 2, record: "f1,r3|f2,r3 then 4 \n:"
NR: 4, NF: 2, record: "f1, r4|f2,r4 then 6 \n: "
NR: 5, NF: 1, record: "f1,r5"
```

Or,

```
$ perl -F"\n" -lane 'BEGIN{ $\=""; $,="|"; $/=""} 
                     printf "NR: %d, NF: %d, record: \"%s\"\n", $., scalar(@F), join($,,@F)' lines
```

works too -- same output.

Ruby *does* has a paragraph mode, but unlike Perl and awk, it has a behavior difference that can matter. If there are more than 2 `\n`, then the runs of `\n` are not ignored. It is equivalent to the regex `/\n\n/` in Ruby vs `/\n\n+/` in awk and Perl. It screws up both the field count and record count on the same input.

Demo:

```
$ ruby -00 -F"\n" -lane 'BEGIN{$\=""; $,="|"}; 
                        printf "NR: %d, NF: %d, record: \"%s\"\n", $.,$F.length,$F.join' lines
NR: 1, NF: 2, record: "f1, r1|f2, r1 then 2 \n:"
NR: 2, NF: 1, record: "f1, r2 then 3 \n:"
NR: 3, NF: 3, record: "|f1,r3|f2,r3 then 4 \n:"
NR: 4, NF: 0, record: ""
NR: 5, NF: 2, record: "f1, r4|f2,r4 then 6 \n: "
NR: 6, NF: 0, record: ""
NR: 7, NF: 0, record: ""
NR: 8, NF: 1, record: "f1,r5"
```

So Ruby's `-00` paragraph mode thinks the same content has 8 records with 9 total fields when Perl and Awk thinks it has 5 records and 8 total fields.

Is there a way to get the same result with Ruby as with Perl and Awk?

Comment: `ruby -F"\n" -lane 'BEGIN{$/=""; $\=""; $,="|"; $i=1}; print "#{$F.join($,)}\t\t#{$i}\n"; $i+=1;' lines` works for me. With the same switches and input / output separators, Ruby behaves a lot like Perl.

Comment: @Stefan: Doh! Please post that. However -- do note that the behavior of `-00` is different than `$\=""` with ruby where perl is the same for each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you use `$/=""` instead of `-00`:

```
$ ruby -F"\n" -lane 'BEGIN{$/=""; $\=""; $,="|"; $i=1};
                     print "#{$F.join($,)}\t\t#{$i}\n"; $i+=1;' lines
```

This is equivalent to the Perl command:

```
$ perl -F"\n" -lane 'BEGIN{$/=""; $\=""; $,="|"; $i=1}
                     print join($,,@F)."\t\t$i\n"; $i++;' lines
```

Both output:

```
f1, r1|f2, r1 then 2 \n:        1
f1, r2 then 3 \n:       2
f1,r3|f2,r3 then 4 \n:      3
f1, r4|f2,r4 then 6 \n:     4
f1,r5       5
```

Comment: No question that the behavior with `ruby -00` is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Like Perl, Ruby only supports a single octal character for `$/` to separate records. (Ruby and Perl share similar global variables.)

So these are three workarounds:

1. Set `$/=""`. In Ruby the behavior of `$/=""` is the same as Perl where runs of `\n` are taken as a single record separator (contrast with `ruby -00`). (Thanks to [Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477037/stefan) for that)
2. 'Slurp' the file and then use a regex to separate the text into records and fields. (This what you need to do for any break between records that is not a single octal character or `\n\n+` in either perl, POSIX awk, or ruby.)
3. Feed the file through awk to remove the excess `\n` and redefine the break as `\n\n`.

#### Example of #1

```
$ ruby -F"\n" -lane 'BEGIN{$\=""; $/=""; $,="|"}; 
                       printf "NR: %d, NF: %d, record: \"%s\"\n", $.,$F.length,$F.join' lines
NR: 1, NF: 2, record: "f1, r1|f2, r1 then 2 \n:"
NR: 2, NF: 1, record: "f1, r2 then 3 \n:"
NR: 3, NF: 2, record: "f1,r3|f2,r3 then 4 \n:"
NR: 4, NF: 2, record: "f1, r4|f2,r4 then 6 \n: "
NR: 5, NF: 1, record: "f1,r5"
```

#### Example of #2

```
$ ruby -e 'i=0
      $<.read.split(/\n\n+/)
        .map {|record| record.split(/\n/)}
        .map {|f| i+=1; printf "NR: %d, NF: %d, record: \"%s\"\n", i,f.length,f.join
                  }' lines
```

#### Example of #3

```
$ ruby -00 -F"\n" -lane 'BEGIN{$/=""; $\=""; $,="|"; $i=1}; 
                     printf "NR: %d, NF: %d, record: \"%s\"\n", $.,$F.length,$F.join' <(awk 'BEGIN{RS=""} {print $0 ORS}' lines)
```

All produce the same output as the first.

The behavior of `ruby -00` is **not** the same as the perl equivalent; it is equivalent of breaking on the regex `/\n\n/`  Only use `-00` if you know that the blocks of data are separated by two `\n` only.

(At least until the [filed bug](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/13736#change-65717) on `-00` is fixed...)

---

(Note: `ruby -0` is different than `ruby -0[some octal value]` The former sets the input record separator to the literal value of `0x00` for use with other Unix utilities that can feed a Nul terminated string, such as `find . print0 | ruby -0 -lane 'puts $_'`)

Comment: FWIW `awk 'BEGIN{RS=""} {print $0 ORS}'` = `awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '1'`